# Configurar log no crontab

Tags: cron

Bom uso o crontab da seguinte forma.

```
0 * * * * wget -q -O /var/www/CronTab.txt https://www.meuseite.com.br/tarefa.php
```

Assim ele sempre cria um arquivo txt 'CronTab.txt' com o resultado, e se tiver algum erro ele vai escrever no arquivo.

O problema é que sempre que ele executa ele cria o arquivo em branco e apaga o arquivo antigo.

Como faço para ele criar o arquivo sem apagar o antigo? Ou seja adicionar o resultado no final do arquivo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html), para anexar ao arquivo de log sem substituir o anterior deve-se utilizar o parâmetro `-a`, ele faz o mesmo que o parâmetro `-o` só que ao invés de substituir o log do arquivo pelo gerado, ele anexa ao antigo.

```
wget http://www.example.com -a Logs.log
```

Fazendo assim o logo gerado se anexado ao arquivo *Logs.log* caso o mesmo existir, caso contrário será criado o arquivo.

### EDIT

Você pode utilizar [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), no simples exemplo abaixo, criei um arquivo **.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
STATUS=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' https://pt.stackoverflow.com/naoexiste)
DATA=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
if [ ! $STATUS -eq 200 ]; then
    echo -e "$DATA - $STATUS" >> /var/www/logs/Logs.log
fi
```

#### Explicação

Parâmetros:

- [**-s**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-s) ou [**--silent**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-s)

  Executa em modo silencioso.
- [**-o**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o) ou [**--output**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-o)

  Escreve a saída em um arquivo em vez de *stdout*.
- [**-w**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-w) ou [**--write-out**](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-w)

  A variável informada nesse parâmetro, será substituída pelo valor ou texto conforme descrito na documentação.

Executamos um condição que verifica se o valor contido na variável `STATUS` é diferente de `200`, caso seja diferente salva o status no log.

Para agendar a tarefa basta:

```
* * * * * /home/USUARIO/executa_tarefa.sh
```

#### Referência

- [Logging and Input File Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html)
- [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: Amigo sa sua forma ficou muito bom, porém acho que o log vai ficar muito grande pois ele esta registrando mesmo quando o arquivo fica em branco (quando não á algum erro). Tem como ele só gravar se tiver algum erro?

Comment: ok, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Amigo só mais um detalhe, o comando `wget http://www.example.com -a Logs.log` funciona perfeitamente, porém está criando um arquivo vazio na mais do servidor, sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Veja a modificação que fiz.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado.